# Wifi connects, works a few minutes and stops

Tags: networking, drivers

I'm starter with Ubuntu and I have some weird problems, I just installed ubuntu, additional drivers, all the updates but here's this weird problem, it connects to the wifi, works perfect like 2 minutes and then it still stays connected but internet doesn't work, here are results

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 69632  0
bnep                   20480  2
wl                   6365184  0
intel_rapl             20480  0
intel_soc_dts_iosf     16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
coretemp               16384  0
uvcvideo               90112  0
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
kvm                   536576  0
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
bluetooth             520192  29 bnep,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
punit_atom_debug       16384  0
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
snd_hda_intel          36864  3
snd_intel_sst_acpi     16384  0
cfg80211              565248  1 wl
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_intel_sst_core     73728  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
cryptd                 20480  0
snd_soc_rt5640        114688  0
snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform    90112  1 snd_intel_sst_core
snd_soc_rl6231         16384  1 snd_soc_rt5640
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
input_leds             16384  0
snd_soc_core          212992  2 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform
snd_compress           20480  1 snd_soc_core
shpchp                 36864  0
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm               106496  8 snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_pcm_dmaengine,snd_hda_core
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
joydev                 20480  0
serio_raw              16384  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
lpc_ich                24576  0
hp_accel               28672  0
mei_txe                20480  0
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
snd                    81920  20 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_core,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform,snd_seq_device,snd_compress
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei                    98304  1 mei_txe
input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
dw_dmac                16384  0
hp_wireless            16384  0
dw_dmac_core           24576  1 dw_dmac
snd_soc_sst_acpi       16384  0
rfkill_gpio            16384  0
i2c_designware_platform    16384  0
8250_dw                16384  0
i2c_designware_core    20480  1 i2c_designware_platform
pwm_lpss_platform      16384  0
pwm_lpss               16384  1 pwm_lpss_platform
spi_pxa2xx_platform    24576  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
i915                 1208320  4
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        147456  1 i915
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  2
psmouse               126976  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
r8169                  81920  0
drm                   360448  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
sdhci_pci              28672  0
mii                    16384  1 r8169
sdhci                  45056  1 sdhci_pci
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
video                  40960  1 i915
i2c_hid                20480  0
fjes                   28672  0
hid                   118784  3 i2c_hid,hid_generic,usbhid
```

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04 and I uninstalled windows already, fully formatted hard drive.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: check dmesg output around the time it stops working and provide the output in the question.